# WPF GridView rows very small/not appearing when bound to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gridview

I'm having trouble getting the data in a DataTable to show up in a GridView. When I use the code below to set the ItemsSource to the Default view for the DataTable I've populated, nothing seems to get added to the grid view. Quite a few rows do seem to appear, but they're very thing (only a few pixels high) and I can't seem to resize them to see if they've got any data in them, almost as though a new row's being created but it's blank. The column headers don't seem to show up either.

```
listView.View = new GridView();

listView.ItemsSource = dataTableSet.Tables[fileName].DefaultView;
```

Like I say the datatable's been populated and the scroll bar does appear when the ItemsSource is set to the data table, but I just can't see any of the data. Do I need to modify the default view of the datatable or something?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of object is listView ? Can you show your XAML ?

Comment: It's an actual ListView object whose view property is set to a GridView. As I say I've sorted it now (with the help the stack overflow community, of course!). Turns out I just needed to add the columns to the GridView manually and bind them to the columns in the data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new GridView. It has no columns set up so it can't show anything.
I'm guessing its rows have an Height=Auto default, that would explain what you see.

The best solution would seem to create and design the GridView beforehand.

If you want auto-columns, maybe better use a DataGrid.

Comment: Yeah thanks I've fixed it now (after about 2 hours of staring at the screen), turns out I had to add the columns to the gridview and bind them one by one before setting the ItemsSource to the data table.